# Widgets in a list don't react to change while using bloc pattern in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

Here I have a `_buildFrontCardDisplaySetting`
which is used to build a list of checkbox to determine which field should be displayed. Each widget in a list is wrapped by a `BlocBuilder`, and in the widget is a `CheckBoxListTile`. In the `CheckBoxListTile`, its value will set to true if the setting option, which is bound to the checkbox, in the list setting in the state class.
My problem is: the UI doesn't react to change if I click the checkbox. I have debugged the code, and it does jump to the `copyWith` method in the class state, but the bloc class doesn't emit any state. I am struggling to find the root cause for my issue. If anyone have an idea here?. Below is my video screenshot and the code:

#### My video screenshot:

[image]

#### My widget:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<FlashCardSettingCubit, FlashCardSettingState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        ...
      },
      child: SimpleDialog(
        children: [
          ..._buildFrontCardDisplaySetting(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
};


 List<Widget> _buildFrontCardDisplaySetting(BuildContext context) {
    final list = FrontSideDisplaySetting.values.map((e) {
      return BlocBuilder<FlashCardSettingCubit, FlashCardSettingState>(
        buildWhen: (prev, current){
          return prev.frontSidesSetting != current.frontSidesSetting;
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
              key: ValueKey(e),
              title: Text(context.frontSetting(e)),
              value: state.frontSidesSetting.contains(e),
              onChanged: (value) {
                context.read<FlashCardSettingCubit>().chooseFrontCardSetting(e);
              });
        },
      );
    }).toList();
    return list;
  }
```

#### My bloc

```
class FlashCardSettingCubit extends Cubit<FlashCardSettingState> {
  FlashCardSettingCubit() : super(FlashCardSettingState.initial());

  void chooseFrontCardSetting(FrontSideDisplaySetting setting) {
    final isContain = state.frontSidesSetting.contains(setting);
    if (isContain) {
      state.frontSidesSetting.remove(setting);
    } else {
      state.frontSidesSetting.add(setting);
    }
    emit(state.copyWith(frontSidesSetting: List.from(state.frontSidesSetting)));
  }

  void chooseBackCardSetting(BackSideDisplaySetting setting) {
    final isContain = state.backSidesSetting.contains(setting);
    if (isContain) {
      state.backSidesSetting.remove(setting);
    } else {
      state.backSidesSetting.add(setting);
    }
    emit(state.copyWith(backSidesSetting: List.from(state.backSidesSetting)));
  }

}
```

#### My state class

```
enum FlashCardSettingStatus { selected, cancel, initial }

class FlashCardSettingState extends Equatable {
  final List<FrontSideDisplaySetting> frontSidesSetting;
  final List<BackSideDisplaySetting> backSidesSetting;
  final FlashCardSettingStatus status;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [frontSidesSetting, backSidesSetting, status];

  const FlashCardSettingState({
    required this.frontSidesSetting,
    required this.backSidesSetting,
    required this.status,
  });

  FlashCardSettingState.initial()
      : this(
            frontSidesSetting: const [],
            backSidesSetting: const [],
            status: FlashCardSettingStatus.initial);

  FlashCardSettingState copyWith({
    List<FrontSideDisplaySetting>? frontSidesSetting,
    List<BackSideDisplaySetting>? backSidesSetting,
    FlashCardSettingStatus? status,
  }) {
    return FlashCardSettingState(
      frontSidesSetting: frontSidesSetting ?? this.frontSidesSetting,
      backSidesSetting: backSidesSetting ?? this.backSidesSetting,
      status: status ?? this.status,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is following line

`emit(state.copyWith(frontSidesSetting: List.from(state.frontSidesSetting)));`

Here you are emitting same state so cubit does not produce this event. What you want is

```dart
    final frontSidesSetting = List.from(state.frontSidesSetting);
    final isContain = fromSideSetting.contains(setting);
    if (isContain) {
      frontSidesSetting.remove(setting);
    } else {
      frontSidesSetting.add(setting);
    }
    emit(state.copyWith(frontSidesSetting: frontSidesSetting));
```

This way, the current state frontSidesSetting and value to be emitted will be different.

Comment: I do make a change by adding or removing an element in this line
` state.backSidesSetting.remove(setting);`. So why doesn't it work as I expected?

Comment: because you are change the variable from state object. You know frontSidesSetting is final in your state class but it can be modified. If you would make it growable = false, you won't be able to add or remove items from it which will make it immutable . So after adding item to list, you have changed value containing current state object so the copywith method is not doing anything.